# Seed list inside an empty list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list

I'm working with KnockoutMVC and it requires strongly type models to use inside the VIEW. I have tried multiple variations of the examples on KnockoutMVC's site including using ENUMS and still could not get it to work. Perhaps this is a problem with the setup of my models.

**MODELS**

```
public class PhoneNumber
{
    public List<NumberTypeClass> Types { get; set; }
    //public NumberType enumType { get; set; }
    //public enum NumberType
    //{
    //    Work,
    //    Home,
    //    Mobile,
    //    Fax
    //}
    private string _number;
    [StringLength(14, MinimumLength = 10, ErrorMessage = "Please use (123) 456-7890 format"), Required]
    public string Number
    {
        get
        {
            this._number = BeautifyPhoneNumber(this._number);
            return this._number;
        }
        set
        {
            this._number = value;
        }
    }

    public string Extension { get; set; }
    public static String BeautifyPhoneNumber(string numberToBeautify)
    {
        //beautifyNumberCode
    } 
}

public class NumberTypeClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string NumberType { get; set; }
}
public class VendorsEditorVendorModel
{
  public string FirstName {Get;set;}
  public string LastName {get;set;}

  public List<Address> Address {get;set;}
  public List<PhoneNumber> Phones {get;set;}
}

public class VendorsEditorModel
{
  public List<VendorsEditorVendorModel> Vendors {get;set;}
}
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
public class VendorsEditorController : BaseController
{
    public ActionResult CreateVendors()
            {// VendorsEditor/CreateVendors

                var vendor = new VendorsEditorModel();

                vendor.Vendors = new List<VendorsEditorVendorModel>();
                vendor.Vendors[0].Phones[0].Types = new List<NumberTypeClass>
        {
            new NumberTypeClass{Id = 0, TypeName = "Mobile"},
            new NumberTypeClass{Id = 0, TypeName = "Work"},
            new NumberTypeClass{Id = 0, TypeName = "Home"}
        };//this throws an error because there is no Vendors[0] ...but how would i populate this list for every Vendor?
                return View(vendor);
            }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot call an empty collection by index [x].  You need to fill your collection from a database or what not before you can access items in it.  If you are just trying to add items to a collection, this is how you do it:

```
    var vendor = new VendorsEditorModel
    {
        Vendors = new List<VendorsEditorVendorModel>
        {
            new VendorsEditorVendorModel
            {
                Phones = new List<PhoneNumber>
                {
                    new PhoneNumber
                    {
                        Types = new List<NumberTypeClass>
                        {
                            new NumberTypeClass {Id = 0, NumberType = "Mobile"}
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

If you just want to add the types to an already populated collection, you can do the following:

```
foreach (var phone in vendor.Vendors.SelectMany(item => item.Phones))
            {
                phone.Types = new List<NumberTypeClass>
                {
                    new NumberTypeClass{Id = 0, NumberType = "Mobile"},
                    new NumberTypeClass{Id = 0, NumberType = "Work"},
                    new NumberTypeClass{Id = 0, NumberType = "Home"}
                };
            }
```